# How can it possible to share different state on different multiple Components in React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have  `Menu` and `MenuItem` react components.

They works like this.

```
        <Menu openOnClick>
          <MenuItem target="/" text="Item 1" active />
          <MenuItem target="#" text="Item 2" parent>
            <MenuItem target="/" text="Item 3" />
            <MenuItem target="/" text="Item 4" />
          </MenuItem>
        </Menu>

        <Menu>
          <MenuItem target="/" text="Item 1" active />
          <MenuItem target="#" text="Item 2" parent>
            <MenuItem target="/" text="Item 3" />
            <MenuItem target="/" text="Item 4" />
          </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
```

Normally  `MenuItem` opens as dowpdown when mouse over but I want to provide also click mode for dropdown.

[clickMode illustrate](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n1GiVxx58cw1KCMb477v1dzMdqW6MiLt/view)

So `MenuItem` has `clickMode` state.I want to this if `Menu` (parent component) has `openOnClick` prop true (given by user) then `MenuItem` `clickMode` state should be true.

I am achiving this in MenuItem component with redux.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log(state.menuReducer.clickMode)
    return {
        clickMode:state.menuReducer.clickMode
    }
}
```

But if there are multiple `Menu` component it doesn't work.Because `redux` store change every dispatch event.

Here is redux state logs.

[image: state logs]

Here is `Menu` reducer.

```
export const menuReducer = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case menuConstants.CLICK_MODE:
            return {
                type: menuConstants.CLICK_MODE,
                clickMode: action.clickMode
            }
        default:
           return state;
    }
}
```

How can handle this?

Many thanks for help.

Comment: can you show us your state? It sounds like it should be possible just to trigger the same actions through a middle-fn for code sanity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are storing a boolean in your state, I would suggest to introduce for every Menu a key ( react already asked you to do it anyway ) and in the handler to dispatch it.

so your action would look something like this:

```
const openOnClick = (id) => ({
  type: "CLICK_MODE",
  id: id
})
```

and your reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  activeMenues: []
}

function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
 switch(action.type) {
   case "CLICK_MODE": return {
     ...state, 
     activeMenues: [...this.state.activeMenues, action.id]
   }
   ...
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but how can I use state on MenuItem. So what is different will be using id?

Comment: The difference is that you will be able to keep track of your active menues. Atm you just know that the user clicked but you don't know where, by introducing id-s you will be able to track that as well.

Answer (score 0):

To do that you can add a high level more of abstraction. I think in your store you have somethig like:

```html
    const state: State = {
      menu:[
       {
       //menuItem
       },
       {
       //menuItem
       }
        .
        .
        .
      ]
      
    }
```

I think you need to do somethink like that:

```html
    const state: State = {
      menus: [
        {
          menu:[
             {
             //menuItem
             },
             {
             //menuItem
             }
              .
              .
              .
          ]
        }
      ...
      ]
      
    }
```

Comment: No.MenuItem  components should use Menu component clickMode prop.